# App crashes due to unrecognized selector sent to VC

Tags: ios, objective-c, exception, uinavigationcontroller, segue

My app crashing due to unrecognized selector sent with segue. I know it's a common question in stackoverflow. I tried all the solution but could not get through this. I think i'm missing something. My current project throws this exception, but a new project with this same code does not throw any exception. Why ? I tried like below code snippet to pass data from FirstViewController to DetailViewController using segue.

In my FirstViewController.h file :

```
 #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
 #import "DetailViewController.h"

 @interface FirstViewController : UIViewController<UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>

 @end
```

In my FirstViewController.m file :

```
 - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
     //if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"detail"]) {
         DetailViewController *vc = (DetailViewController *)[segue destinationViewController];
         vc.nameStr = @"Nuibb";
     //}
 }
```

In my DetailViewController.h file :

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface DetailViewController : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *nameStr;
@end
```

In my DetailViewController.m file :

```
#import "DetailViewController.h"

@interface DetailViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *label;

@end

@implementation DetailViewController
@synthesize nameStr;
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    self.label.text = nameStr;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

And i'm getting this error message in log -

```
2015-03-11 10:27:24.145 bdipo[1185:18722] -[UINavigationController setNameStr:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fe928dad8c0
2015-03-11 10:27:24.147 bdipo[1185:18722] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UINavigationController setNameStr:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fe928dad8c0'
```

Comment: Look at your segue's `destinationViewController`. It's probably not a `DetailViewController` like what you typecast it to.

Comment: may be [segue destinationViewController] is UINavigationController not is  DetailViewController so it not have nameStr property

Comment: Actually between FirstViewController and DetailViewController, there is a Navigation controller in my storyboard. Now what should i do ?

Comment: [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/p0qhavnqbb7yb0o/Screenshot%202015-03-11%2010.58.40.png?dl=0) is the screen shot of my storyboard.

Comment: This is your prepare for segue but where is your segue firing code, in which action method are you firing the segue?

Comment: Segue is firing on tableView's cell selection of FirstViewController to the DetailViewController in storyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need one Navigation Controller in any app which loads at launch time and will handle navigating the full stack of view controllers for you. It needs to be the root view controller, with the "Is Initial View Controller" box checked (under Attributes Inspector, View Controller) to give it that start-arrow pointing in to the left side of the view.

[image]

Assuming your NewsTVC is the first view controller you want to show,  delete the navigation view controller in your storyboard. Select NewsTVC, go up to your XCode toolbar and select "Editor --> Embed In --> Navigation Controller".

[image]

A navigation controller will be created that segues into your NewsTVC. Make sure "Is Initial View Controller" is selected for the new Navigation Controller, and drag a new segue between you NewsTVC prototype cell and the DetailVC. This should organize your stack so the segue runs properly.

[image]

Comment: And also override the prepareForSegue method in your NewsTVC like Light Yagami pointed out. You'll find it commented out in the bottom of your boiler plate implementation code when you generate a custom UITableViewController class file.

Comment: Actually i have no initial root view controller. Because for the first time user will go to login screen and after that he/she always start app from tabbar controller without seeing that login screen. I handle this in the appdelegate file.

Comment: [this (25% scale)](https://www.dropbox.com/s/dbwaqmmsapcfadq/Screenshot%202015-03-11%2012.02.43.png?dl=0) and [this(50%)](https://www.dropbox.com/s/60nj3d2eu0rt0tc/Screenshot%202015-03-11%2012.02.23.png?dl=0) is the screenshot of full storyboard. Before every view controller of each tab in my storyboard, i just embed in a navigation controller from Editor>Embed In> Navigation Controller. Is not it a proper way ? Please let me know if i do mistake. Thanks.

Comment: You need ONE Navigation Controller for the whole app that is the initial view controller. It does not need a tab bar controller. As the root view controller, the Navigation Controller will contain all your other view controllers as sub-views and will superimpose it's own view with the nav buttons on every view controller that it leads to. 
If you want to present a login screen, that's not something I've done before, but perhaps you can push a modal view over the first view controller that loads that takes login credentials? Or there maybe be way to hide the navigation bar for you login screen.

Comment: okay, it's working now. What i did wrong is i added a navigation controller between FirstViewController and DetailViewController that is needless. After deleting that controller, it's working perfectly. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You can access your view as below

```
DetailViewController *detailVC =
        [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DetailViewController"];//modify this identifier name as per your StoryBoardIDentifier for detailview at storyboard..
detailVC.nameStr=@"Nuibb";
[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailVC animated:NO];//if you want to push to detail view from first view
```

Hope it helps you...

Answer (score 1):

V1(segue name = xyz)-->NavController-->(ROOT)VC2

In your vc1's didselectforRowAtIndexPath or any other Action method write this code.

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifire:@"xyz"];
```

Then override the method -

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
 if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"xyz"]) {
     DetailViewController *vc = (DetailViewController *)[segue destinationViewController];
     vc.nameStr = @"Nuibb";
 }
}
```

Inside DetailViewController.h declare a property first.

```
@property(nonatomic,strong)NSString *nameStr;
```

Answer (score 0):

On `tableView` `didSelectRowAtIndex` a `UINavigationController` is segued as per your storyboard and your `navigationController` is not having any property named `nameStr`

You will have to segue `detailViewController` direct. As `UINavigationController` cannot pe pushed in navigation.